# Clicking sound from speakers

Tags: speakers, sound-card, ubuntu-20.04

I have the following problem on a Ubuntu 20.04.1 desktop machine. I cannot make a test on other operating systems because Ubuntu is the only one installed.

When the OS is not playing any output sounds, I hear a clicking sound + noise from the output speakers. When the OS "takes control" of the sound output, the noise and the clicking sound disappears even during the silent intervals.

For example:

1. if I open the system settings and go to the "Sound" item, the noise disappears and the speakers become completely silent. If I move to any other item in Settings (Network, Bluetooth, etc.), the clicking and the noise restart a few seconds after I have left the "Sound" item. There are no noise or clicking sounds as long as I stay on the "Sound" menu item, even if I stay on that item for minutes.
2. If I play a video on youtube, there is no noise during the silent fragments of the video. The same applies to calls, music, etc.

This is not a huge issue because, when it is likely that some sounds might be played, the noise disappears (calls, videos, etc), but the noise is quite annoying in all the other cases (my current solution is to keep open the application "Settings" with the item "Sound" selected).

May be it is related to some power optimizations made by the OS (as suggested by some pages I found on the internet), but this is a desktop machine and I can give up that optimization.

Is there any way to ask the OS to always keep "using" the sound subsystem?

I have already tried the solutions [here](https://askubuntu.com/questions/220223/constant-noise-in-speakers-and-headphones) (loopback, automute), with no success.